# md5 encryption node js and magento not matching..

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, magento, encryption

I have created login service in both magento and node js. In magento if customer is registered with password, the password is encrypted with md5 salt key value.
If i am using crypto node js module to decrypt the magento password it is throwing error.

```
Error: Unknown cipher
    at Error (native)
    at new Decipher (crypto.js:210:16)
    at Object.Decipher (crypto.js:207:12)
    at D:\Workspace\mobileapp\routes\users.js:30:24
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Workspace\mobileapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Workspace\mobileapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at D:\Workspace\mobileapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at param (D:\Workspace\mobileapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:349:14)
```

Only if i decrypt the magento password i can verify my login password matches and i can proceed. I tried to encrypt my node js login password but the password doesnot matches..

Comment: You cannot decrypt hashes. MD5 is a one-way function. But it's not secure. You need to use strong password hashing like scrypt, bcrypt and PBKDF2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: Anyway, if you have a problem with your code, then you need to show it.

Answer (score 0):

> In magento if customer is registered with password, the password is encrypted with md5 salt key value.

There's a lot to unpack here.

1. Magento should be using bcrypt, not MD5.
2. MD5 isn't encryption.
3. What's a "salt key value"?

> If i am using crypto node js module to decrypt the magento password it is throwing error.

You can't decrypt MD5, because MD5 is not encryption.

MD5 is a hash function. Hash functions are not encryption.

Hash functions are cryptographic! But not all cryptographic algorithms are encryption.

[Read this to understand the difference](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).